# Run Multiple Queries and Export To Different CSV Files

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script that will run a sql query and if results are returned export those results to a csv file.  I need to take that a step further now and have  something similar to this: -- Run Query 1, if it returned results save.  Run Query 2, if it returned results save, Run Query 3, if it returned results save.

```
$server = "Main"
$database = "hellfire"

$query1 = "Select * from mousetrap"
$query2 = "Select * from mickey"
$query3 = "Select * from brimstone"

$templatefile = @"C:\book1.csv"
$savedirectory = @"C:\ExportedFromSQL\Results\"

#Actual Conenction To SQL Server Goes here
#for brevity I am omitting

#check if query returned results
if ($SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) - ge 1)
{
    #this is where my catch comes in
    #if $query1 was executed I want to save the file as mouse
    #if $query2 was executed I want to save the file as mi
    #if $query3 was executed I want to save the file as stone

    #$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $templatefile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: How do you decide which query to run?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - as long as the correct query is associated with the correct filename they can run in any order.

Comment: Let me repeat the question: how do you decide which query to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function to run your query, keeps it simple and you always know which query you are executing.

```
Function Execute-SQLquery {
    param ($QueryName, $QueryString, $ResultDir)

    #Actual Conenction To SQL Server Goes here
    #for brevity I am omitting

    if ($SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) -ge 1)
    {
        $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv (join-path $ResultDir ($QueryName + ".csv")) -NoTypeInformation
        return $true
    } else {
        return $false
    }
}

#Call your function
    if (Execute-SQLquery "mousetrap" "Select * from mousetrap" $savedirectory) {
        if (Execute-SQLquery "mickey" "Select * from mickey" $savedirectory) {
            Execute-SQLquery "brimstone" "Select * from brimstone" $savedirectory
        }
    }
```